# WSO2: How to use the response of one api as a input parameter to another separate API

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Can some one please let me know or guide me to achieve this:

I am calling one login API which returns authorization ticket. I need to capture the ticket information from the response message of first API and use it to invoke another API.

First and Second API are separate ones. First API is for login and second API is for creation of entity.

I have read through many posts and blogs but not able to proceed further and I am fairly new in WSO2. Can some one please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using a proxy service, mediation sequences and mediators. You will need 2 sequences which perform,

1. Log in, read the response and extract the token which then set to a property mediator. So that the second sequence can retrieve it.
2. Read the token which was set from the sequence1 and invoke the next API.

Then you can create a single proxy service in ESB, which invokes sequence 1 and 2.

Please go through the documentation[1] on Message Mediation for more detailed information on how to use different mediators.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Mediating+Messages

Comment: Thanks..
But first API is having post method. So how can we have the response in same Sequence? pls help

Comment: Please check this. https://medium.com/p/5d7e234c61c?source=email-d1a20bbcb85a-1536292816439-writer_stats. This is also a similar scenario. Except, saving the token in registry. You can use a property mediator for that. Use call or send mediator to send the next request in the same sequence.

Comment: Thanks again. I will go through this and will update here